# PrismaClientValidationError: Missing required argument in connectOrCreate

Tags: postgresql, next.js, amazon-rds, prisma

**Problem:**
When I try and send/store data in my database I get this error. Specifically, I am trying to create/save a classroom with student names.
**Tech Used:**
Prisma/Postgres connected to AWS RDS and Next.js, deployed on Vercel, etc.
**Error Message**

```
PrismaClientValidationError: Argument data.classrooms.upsert.0.create.students.connectOrCreate.0.create.school.connect of type schoolWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument.
Argument data.classrooms.upsert.0.update.students.upsert.0.create.school.connect of type schoolWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument.
    at Document.validate (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:29501:20)
    at serializationFn (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:33060:19)
    at runInChildSpan (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:22550:12)
    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:33067:31)
    at async PrismaClient._request (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:32994:16)
    at async profile (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/user/profile.js:175:27)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:366:9)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:481:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:735:37)
    at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:247:36) {
  clientVersion: '4.9.0'
}
```

**DB Models with relationships:**
 school (1 to many w/students); students (many to many with classrooms); teachers (one to many with students, many to many with classrooms)
**Code/Prisma Query**

```
export default async (req, res) => {
...
        classroom.students.forEach((student) => {
          const totalStudentPoints = student.rewardsRecieved.reduce(
            (totalPoints, reward) => {
              return totalPoints + reward.pointValue;
            },
            0
          );
          groups[student.group.name] += totalStudentPoints;
        });
        return { ...classroom, groupsTotalPoints: groups };
      });
      user.classrooms = newClassrooms;
      res.json(user);
    } else {
      console.log("Could Not Find User");
      res.status(401).json({
        error: "Not authorized",
      });
    }
  }

  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    const connectStudents = (shouldUpsert) => {
      const students = req.body.students;
      return students.map((student) => {
        const UNSAFEHASH = md5(student.id);
        const studentQuery: any = {
          where: {
            id: student.id,
          },

          create: {
            id: student.id,
            firstName: student.firstName,
            lastName: student.lastName,
            profilePicture: student.profilePicture,
            userKey: UNSAFEHASH,

            school: {
              connect: {
                id: req.body.schoolId,
              },
            },

            group: {
              connect: {
                id: student.group.id,
              },
            },
          },
        };
        if (shouldUpsert) {
          studentQuery.update = {
            firstName: student.firstName,
            lastName: student.lastName,
            profilePicture: student.profilePicture,
            userKey: UNSAFEHASH,
            group: {
              connect: {
                id: student.group.id,
              },
            },
          };
        }
        return studentQuery;
      });
    };

    try {
      const user = await prisma.staff.update({
        where: {
          id: session.id,
        },
        data: {
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          classrooms: {
            upsert: [
              {
                where: {
                  id: req.body.classId || "-1",
                },
                create: {
                  // id: req.body.classId,
                  name: req.body.className,
                  subject: req.body.classSubject,
                  students: {
                    connectOrCreate: connectStudents(false),
                  },
                },
                update: {
                  name: req.body.className,
                  subject: req.body.classSubject,
                  students: {
                    upsert: connectStudents(true),
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
```

Take a look at the PUT request and the prima.staff.update method more specifically. I was looking at the UPSERT I have there, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Can you check that `req.body.schoolId` or `req.body.schoolId` values are not undefined?

Comment: So just to be specific: I added console.log("STUDENTID", req.body.studentId) just before I use it, just below the connectStudents function. BUT... when I send the PUT request I get a 500 error and nothing logs.

Comment: ALSO - when I inspect the network tab, of course it returns a 500 error, but also most of the updated/saved info:
students: [,…]
   0:{firstName: "asdf", lastName: "", group: {name: "RED", id: "8cabd2a4-92f9- 
   4e29-b868-f2c29d120f4f"},…}
   firstName:"asdf"
group:{name: "RED", id: "8cabd2a4-92f9-4e29-b868-f2c29d120f4f"}
    id: "ab9e2893-93aa-4d92-855d-873cc9b82ebf"
    lastName: ""
    points:0
    rewardsRecieved: []

Comment: I moved the console log to the right place and yes it studentId does come back as undefined.

Comment: GOT IT!! So, it ended up being very simple. I wrote http instead of https on my endpoint. Crazy. But thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you were able to figure it out! :)